# Ways of dealing with humongous amounts of data? (reading, plotting etc.)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, bigdata, boxplot, jupyter-lab

I have to work with gigantic amounts of trading data. I'm talking about around 127,000,000 rows in a BigQuery environment. I am working in a Jupyterlab notebook with limited memory, which causes constant crashes after a certain point and a certain amount of data. My goal is too generate plots like the following ones:
[image: goal].

[image: way]

Second one generated by this code:

```
N=24
c = ['hsl('+str(h)+',50%'+',50%)' for h in np.linspace(0, 360, N)]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Box(
    x=hour_dataframes[i]['hour'],
    y=hour_dataframes[i]['priceNum'],
    marker_color=c[i]
    ) for i in range(int(N))])

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, zeroline=True, showticklabels=True),
    yaxis=dict(zeroline=True, gridcolor='white'),
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(233,233,233)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(233,233,233)',
    autosize=False,
    width=1500,
    height=1000,
    title="August",
)

fig.show()
```

As you can see, there are a lot of outliers and just scrolling over the plot makes the notebook lag. At a certain amount (e.g. for a whole year) I can't even read in the data **without Jupyter crashing**. I have found some alternative approaches by aggregating it with the help of BigQuery, but then some important information is lost, as you can see on the following (boring) plot.
[image: alt]
Generated by this code:

```
N = 24
boxes={}

for i in range(int(N)):
    boxes[i] =[
        {
            "label" : str(i),
            "whislo": float(df_2022.iloc[i]["minValue"]),
            "q1"    : float(df_2022.iloc[i]["quartile25"]),
            "med"   : df_2022.iloc[i]["median"],
            "q3"    : df_2022.iloc[i]["quartile75"],
            "whishi" : df_2022.iloc[i]["maxValue"],
            "fliers": []
    }]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.set_title("Preisschwankungen aller Kontrakte 2022")
ax.set_xlabel("Uhr")
ax.set_ylabel("Preis")

for i in range(int(N)):
    
    ax.bxp(boxes[i], positions=[i], showfliers=False)
```

I tried to sample the set in BigQuery (with the help of `RAND()`)but didn't found an efficient way without losing important data.

Since I don't really know what to try or search for anymore, I thought maybe some of you guys on here have some useful tips. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using plotly (the plot looks like it)? If so, did you try changing the [rendermode](https://plotly.com/python/webgl-vs-svg/) to webgl? What exactly is crashing: is your browser showing "page crashed", or is the kernel dying?

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess this in BigQuery. The QUANTILES for the box plot can be calculated in a table. The outliners are the values above Q3 or below Q1. These can be filtered by joining both tables and returning a 3rd table.

```
create temp table 
 tbl as (Select d, rand() y from unnest(generate_array(1,1000)) as d, unnest(generate_array(1,1000)) as tmp);

create temp table 
QUANTILE as (
SELECT *
from (
SELECT * except(Q)
from (
select d,APPROX_QUANTILES(y,3) Q
from tbl
group by 1
),unnest(Q) Q_ with offset as Qoff )
pivot(min(Q_) Q for Qoff in (0,1,2,3,4,5) )
);

Select * from tbl
left join QUANTILE
using(d)
#where y<Q_1 or y>Q_3   # :
qualify y<Q_1 or y>Q_3 or y=min(y) over (partition by d)
```